# Folder Processing with Bash

Tags: bash, macos

My goal is to automatically organize a number of CSV files in a folder. 
The current structure looks like:

[CSV folder]
Cell1_image1_summary.csv
Cell1_image1_all.csv
Cell1_image2_summary.csv
Cell1_image2_all.csv
Cell8_image1_summary.csv
Cell8_image1_all.csv
Cell8_image2_summary.csv
Cell8_image2_all.csv

The name "Cell1", "Cell8" will vary, but will be known amongst a small number (i.e., there are ten Cells).

I would like it to look like:
[Cell1]->[Summary]->list of CSVs with cell1_image_summary.csv
          ->[All]->list of CSVs with cell1_image_all.csv

[Cell8]->[Summary]->list of CSVs with cell8_image_summary.csv
          ->[All]->list of CSVs with cell8_image_all.csv

I have a combination of a few different scripts that eventually get me there, namely

```
[[ -d Cell1 ]] && mv Cell1*.csv Cell1 || { mkdir Cell1 && mv Cell1*.csv Cell1; }
```

to accomplish the first part (but this requires me to manually code in the Cell names). Then I use

```
find CSV -mindepth 1 -type f -name '*SUMMARY.csv' | while read -r FILE; do
DIRNAME=${FILE%/*}
mkdir -p "$DIRNAME/SUMMARY" && mv "$FILE" "$DIRNAME/SUMMARY/"
done
```

```
find CSV -mindepth 1 -type f -name '*all.csv' | while read -r FILE; do
DIRNAME=${FILE%/*}
mkdir -p "$DIRNAME/ALL" && mv "$FILE" "$DIRNAME/ALL/"
done
```

In two separate calls to eventually make the two subfolders 
 (I call these last two calls on the [CSV Folder] as it was designed to work on multiple [Cell1][Cell2]...[Cell8] folders.

Needless to say this is terrible but was hacked together by someone who doesn't know any bash with help here...

Would appreciate any thoughts on how to make it more efficient (and learn more bash in the process). Alternatively, I'm on Mac OS X, so if there is something else (I've tried Hazel and Applescript with little success) I'm open to non-bash solutions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

untested:

```
cd "CSV folder"
for f in *.csv; do
    cell=${f%%_*}               # what's before the first underscore
    mkdir -p "./$cell/"{Summary,All}
    case "$f" in
        *_summary*) mv -v "$f" "./$cell/Summary" ;;
        *_all*)     mv -v "$f" "./$cell/All" ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Tested - Works perfectly!